# Dhall Lang Invalid List Type

Tags: json, github, terraform, dhall

I am really wanting to use Dhall lang to solve an issue that I have with using the Github Terraform Provider.

See: https://github.com/etaty/example-dhall-terraform-github

However, I have never used Dhall before and really only have this one use case for using it.

I am wanting to debug the errors that I am getting in this github repo to create the github.tf file.

The error that I get is as follows:

```
Error: Invalid type for ❰List❱

63│                        [] : Optional (List a)
64│
```

I have included line 63 below and where this error is being referenced. I went online to  do alot of research around this however, I have not had any success.

```
in let emptyListToOptional = \(a: Type) -> \(l: List a) ->
    if (null a l) then [] : List Natural , Optional (List a)
    else [l] : List Natural, Optional (List a)

in let build = \(config: T.Config) ->
        let github_membership = map T.GithubUser T.TF/GithubMembership makeGithubMembership config.users
    in let github_team = map T.Team T.TF/GithubTeam makeGithubTeam config.teams
    in let github_team_membership = concat T.TF/GithubTeamMembership (map T.GithubUser (List T.TF/GithubTeamMembership) makeGithubTeamMembership config.users)
    in {
          github_membership = emptyListToOptional T.TF/GithubMembership github_membership
        , github_team = emptyListToOptional T.TF/GithubTeam github_team
        , github_team_membership = emptyListToOptional T.TF/GithubTeamMembership github_team_membership
    }

in {
```

Any Help Would Be Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: For up-to-date introductions to Dhall, see https://docs.dhall-lang.org/tutorials/Getting-started_Generate-JSON-or-YAML.html and https://docs.dhall-lang.org/tutorials/Language-Tour.html.

Answer (score 3):

The code you linked to is out of date; the way you specify `Optional` values has changed. For instance, the lines

```
in let emptyListToOptional = \(a: Type) -> \(l: List a) ->
    if (null a l) then [] : List Natural , Optional (List a)
    else [l] : List Natural, Optional (List a)
```

were originally (from the repository)

```
in let emptyListToOptional = \(a: Type) -> \(l: List a) ->
    if (null a l) then [] : Optional (List a)
    else [l]: Optional (List a)
```

which should now read

```
in let emptyListToOptional = \(a: Type) -> \(l: List a) ->
    if (null a l) then None (List a)
    else Some l
```

Comment: For more details, see: https://docs.dhall-lang.org/howtos/migrations/Deprecation-of-old-Optional-literal-syntax.html